# Geometry Node Creation

Tags: node-editor, geometry

Is there a tutorial that explains how to create an individual geometry node? I don't mean a node network, I mean the node itself.

Answer (score 7):

If you meant using python:

- Here is a topic with many example of custom node interface https://devtalk.blender.org/t/extra-nodes-for-geometrynodes/20942

If you meant using C++:

- See this topic by Elie https://devtalk.blender.org/t/tutorial-about-writing-a-custom-geometry-node-for-blender/24561

If you meant using blender native functionality:

- Use control+G to group a node, then in the N panel you are able to expose inputs/outputs

Comment: Amazing! Would it be possible to program a node with it (C++) without recompiling Blender completely and implement the node independently as an addon? ...or would that only work as an addon via Python? Or would it work at all to implement own nodes as addon?

Comment: although i have no idea - i cannot imagine that this works without recompiling...else there would be hundreds of GN add-ons...wouldn't it?

Comment: but the links are really great and already amazing stuff can be done...!!! WOW

Comment: @Chris no you need to recompile, the API is intentionally weak so you'll submit patches

Comment: That’s great! Would be even greater, if we could change geometry too…or…as in animation nodes - you can use script nodes and do whatever you want!